Required to Leave UK Tier 4 Student Visa
I applied for a temporary withdrawal from my studies in the UK a few months ago. Thereafter, I received a letter through an email from the home office in which it was stated that "Your permission to enter as a student has been cancelled so that it now ends in 60 days," which I did.
I am in my home country now and applying for another Tier 4 student visa again to resume my studies. I am confused because in the visa application process there is a section that states that "were you ever deported, refused, required to leave, etc. Does "required to leave" refer to me in this case?
Summary: Does temporarily withdrawing from a degree program fall under "required to leave" when applying again for a UK Tier 4 student visa to resume studies?

Why the confusion? The question in the application is unambiguous. Your visa was cancelled and you had to leave the UK

@Traveller by that logic, wouldn't a visit to the UK on a tourist visa also count as "required to leave"?

@guest12356 By implication all visa holders are ‘required to leave’ (ie by the visa expiry date), irrespective of the visa class. That is not the same as being required to leave because your visa is cancelled before its expiry date.
